# How to call a method using user input

Tags: ruby

I have 2 methods -- Add and Delete -- I was wanting to call them using user input.

So instead of this long code

```
def delete; end
def add; end

case gets.chomp
    when 'Add'
      add
    when 'Delete'
      delete
end
```

I'm looking for something along the lines of what the key word `eval` does.

```
eval gets.chomp
```

That way if the input is 'add' then it will execute the 'add' method

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Edit---
I'm an idiot. Eval works. It appeared to not be working because I had an error else where. Regardless thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def a
    puts "1"
end

def b
    puts "2"
end

while true
    eval(gets.chomp)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke methods by symbol using [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
send gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should work if tweeked like this:

```
def delete; end
def add; end

puts "please chose a method add or delete"
ans = gets.chomp.downcase

case ans
    when 'add'
      add
    when 'delete'
      delete
    else 
puts "nothing selected"
end
```

Comment: I specifically said I didn't want a case statement like code

Answer (score 0):

You can use "send" method, first put your methods in a class then
Try this:

```
    class Methods
       def show
         print "show"
       end
     end
    print "Enter your method name: "
    methodName = gets.chomp
    methodName.to_sym
    myMethods = Methods.new
    meMethods.send(methodName)
```

Try it!
You can use this way to make new programming languages or HUGE programs.

Comment: I ment at the last line myMethods not meMethods